# PHP trying to include array of glob()'d directories and is not finding last one

Tags: php

Hello I have the following method:

```
private static function loadIncludes()
{
    // prepare array of files from folders
    $files = array(
        glob(self::libPath()."/*.php"),
        glob(self::controllersPath()."/*.php"),
        glob(self::extensionsPath()."/*.php"),
    );

    // include files
    foreach ($files as $set)
    {
        if (is_array($set)) foreach ($set as $file)
        {
            require_once($file);
        }
    }
}
```

If I print_r the $files array it contains all the files but for some reason its not doing a require_once() on the last array item (/home/***/app/extensions/Controller.php)
see output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => /home/***/app/lib/CApp.php
            [1] => /home/***/app/lib/CController.php
            [2] => /home/***/app/lib/CDb.php
            [3] => /home/***/app/lib/CView.php
        )

    [1] => Array
(
            [0] => /home/***/app/controllers/SiteController.php
        )

    [2] => Array
(
            [0] => /home/***/app/extensions/Controller.php
        )

)
```

Comment: This should work. Are you sure the file hasn't been included already? Also, in my opinion, `if (is_array($set)) foreach ($set as $file) { }` is bad coding style. It probably could be clearer than that.

Comment: how do you know it's not doing `require_once`? maybe it's loaded already

Answer (score -1):

As the print_r shows even when there is only a single result it still an array,

I believe the if (is_array($set)) can be left out.

As for why only the last one doesn't work i cannot say,

try debugging better by echoing every step of all for each loops

Comment: *"As for why only the last one doesn't work i cannot say"* well it's not an answer then.

Comment: thank you captain obvious, to me the code looks good and i cannot test because i dont have ur class/file setup. I'm still giving directions to how you can solve your problem, You're wecome.

Comment: Well it's not my problem, it's the OP's problem. And this is still not an answer, it's a nice comment though. You probably should read and make sure you're addressing the right person before you say things.

Comment: I actually found out the problem was that I was including the files in the wrong order!